# SQL Server recompile marked stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

With the following script, I've tried to recompile all our stored procedures on the database because we're upgrading to SQL Server 2012 (from 2005) and I want to make sure beforehand, that they don't break.

```
DECLARE @schema VARCHAR(20),
        @spName VARCHAR(MAX),
        @fullName VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE storedProcedureCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT SPECIFIC_SCHEMA, SPECIFIC_NAME
    FROM ASZ_GWZ.information_schema.routines 
    WHERE routine_type = 'PROCEDURE'

OPEN storedProcedureCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM storedProcedureCursor INTO @schema, @spName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @fullName = @schema + '.' + @spName
    EXEC sp_recompile @objname = @fullName

    FETCH NEXT FROM storedProcedureCursor INTO @schema, @spName
END 

CLOSE storedProcedureCursor
DEALLOCATE storedProcedureCursor
```

Unfortunately, the result was a little bit different from what I expected, since the stored procedures were only **marked** for recompilation and didn't actually get recompiled.

> Object 'dbo.xyz' was successfully marked for recompilation.

How can I really recompile all (or all now for recompilation marked) stored procedures?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That is what the sp_recompile procedure does. Here is the documentation page. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181647.aspx Here is the very first sentence..."Causes stored procedures, triggers, and user-defined functions to be recompiled the next time that they are run."

Comment: Since you are upgrading from 2005 to 2012 this exercise is pointless. The execution plans will need to be cached in 2012 so everything will be recompiled anyway. Save yourself the hassle. Do your upgrade. Update statistics, rebuild indexes etc. Your execution plan cache will be a little sluggish at first but it "caches" up pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run a stored procedure for it to recompile. To compile a stored proc basically means that the execution plan for the stored proc gets cached. Whether you use sp_recompile or create a stored proc `WITH RECOMPILE`, you're just telling SQL that the execution plan needs to be re-cached. That sp_recompile only removes the existing execution plan.

> The sp_recompile system stored procedure forces a recompile of a
>   stored procedure the next time that it is run. It does this by
>   deleting the existing plan from the procedure cache forcing a new plan
>   to be created the next time that the procedure is run.

More Info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190439(v=sql.110).aspx